# Apache redirect secure to nonsecure for certain subdomains

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, redirect, subdomain

I have several domains with the same subdomain, that may or not be accessed securely. I need to redirect every request that comes in from **redirect**.somesite.com to be redirected to a secure site. I need the original url, domain, and if the site was requested as secure or not.

> **http://redirect.site1.com/page?id=1**
>
> Redirects to
>
> https://process.site4.com/page?id=3&domain=**a.site1.com**&secure=**0**

and

> **https://redirect.site2.com/page?id=2**
>
> Redirects to
>
> https://process.site4.com/page?id=3&domain=**a.site2.com**&secure=**1**

and

> **http://redirect.site3.com/page?id=3**
>
> Redirects to
>
> https://process.site4.com/page?id=3&domain=**a.site3.com**&secure=**0**

and

> **http://www.site3.com/page?id=3**
>
> Remains as
>
> http://www.site3.com/page?id=3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want the id query strings to match in the redirect?

Try this in your .htaccess file in your document root (or in your server/vhost config, change the `^page$` regex to `^/page$`):

```
RewriteEngine On

# check if secure= is already set, and set it either to 1 or 0
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !secure=
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^page$ /page?%{QUERY_STRING}&secure=1 [L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !secure=
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^page$ /page?%{QUERY_STRING}&secure=0 [L]

# check if the host starts with a "redirect." and match against the "/page" URI
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^redirect\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^page$ https://process.site4.com/page?domain=a.%1 [QSA,R,L]
```

The QSA at the last rule ensures that the 'secure=' and the original 'id=' query string parameters get tacked onto the URL.

Comment: How about only apply the rules to those sites that start with the process subdomain, but this looks like what I need.